# Automatically create a subnet for each AWS availability zone in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is there a better way to optime the code below so I don't have to ask for availability zone again and again instead can do it in once. as the region is variable so I cant define hardcoded availability zone. can you guys please I want my public subnets to be /24

```
provider "aws" {
    region = var.region
}

resource "aws_vpc" "app_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags = {
    Name = var.vpc_name
  }
}


data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

#provision public subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_01" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_01
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_01"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association.dns_resolver]
}
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_02" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_02
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_02"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association.dns_resolver]
}
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_03" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_03
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[2]
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_03"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association.dns_resolver]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

An important hazard to consider with the `aws_availability_zones` data source is that the set of available zones can change over time, and so it's important to write your configuration so that you don't find yourself trapped in a situation where Terraform thinks you intend to replace a subnet that you are currently using and therefore cannot destroy.

A key part of that is ensuring that Terraform understands that each of the subnets belongs to a specific availability zone, so that when the set of availability zones changes Terraform can either add a new subnet for a new availability zone or remove an existing subnet for a now-removed availability zone, without affecting the others that haven't changed. The easiest way to achieve that is to use [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) with the set of availability zones:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each = aws_avaiability_zones.available.names

  # ...
}
```

The above will declare subnet instances with addresses that each include the availability zone name, like this:

- `aws_subnet.public["eu-west-1a"]`
- `aws_subnet.public["eu-west-1b"]`
- `aws_subnet.public["eu-west-1e"]`

Because they are identified by the availability zone name, Terraform can see that each subnet belongs to a particular availability zone.

For subnets in particular there is an additional challenge: we must assign each subnet its own CIDR block, which means we need a systematic way of allocating IP address space to availability zones so that the networks won't get renumbered by future changes to the set of availability zones.

The documentation for [the `aws_availability_zone` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/availability_zone) includes an example of declaring a mapping table that assigns each region and each availability zone a number between 1 and 14 which is then used to populate one of the octets of the IP address to create a separate prefix per (region, AZ) pair. That example creates only a single VPC and a single subnet, but we can expand on that by using `for_each` to do it for each of the availability zones, as long as we update the mapping tables whenever we use a new region or a new availability zone suffix letter is assigned (up to 14 of each):

```
variable "region_number" {
  # Arbitrary mapping of region name to number to use in
  # a VPC's CIDR prefix.
  default = {
    us-east-1      = 1
    us-west-1      = 2
    us-west-2      = 3
    eu-central-1   = 4
    ap-northeast-1 = 5
  }
}

variable "az_number" {
  # Assign a number to each AZ letter used in our configuration
  default = {
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    d = 4
    e = 5
    f = 6
    # and so on, up to n = 14 if that many letters are assigned
  }
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

# Determine all of the available availability zones in the
# current AWS region.
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"
}

# This additional data source determines some additional
# details about each VPC, including its suffix letter.
data "aws_availability_zone" "all" {
  for_each = aws_avaiability_zones.available.names

  name = each.key
}

# A single VPC for the region
resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet("10.1.0.0/16", 4, var.region_number[data.aws_region.current.name])
}

# A subnet for each availability zone in the region.
resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = aws_availability_zone.all

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.example.id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.example.cidr_block, 4, var.az_number[each.value.name_suffix])
}
```

For example, if we were working in `us-west-2` and there were availability zones `us-west-2a` and `us-west-2c`, the above would declare:

- A single `aws_vpc.example` with CIDR block `10.1.48.0/20`, where 48 is the decimal representation of hex 0x30, where 3 is the number for us-west-2.
- A subnet `aws_subnet.example["us-west-2a"]` in `us-west-2a` with CIDR block `10.1.49.0/24`, where 49 is the decimal representation of hex 0x31.
- A subnet `aws_subnet.example["us-west-2c"]` in `us-west-2c` with CIDR block `10.1.51.0/24`, where 51 is the decimal representation of hex 0x33.

Notice that there is no subnet for `10.1.50.0/24`, because 50 (hex 0x32) is reserved for a hypothetical `us-west-2b`. By allocating these addresses statically by subnet letter we can ensure that they will not change over time as availability zones are added and removed.

Answer (score 4):

You can automate creation of subnets using [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) and [cidrsubnets](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrsubnet.html).

An example would be:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {

  count             = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.app_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.app_vpc.cidr_block, 8, count.index)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet_${count.index}"
  }
  
  depends_on = [aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association.dns_resolver]
}
```

The above will automatically create subnet in each AZ as well as assing
cidr block (/24, assuming that vpc is /16) to it.

Comment: i know but i am unable to figure it out how to give /24 can you please help me also will it possible to take user data for cidr ?

Comment: Hi `cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.app_vpc.cidr_block, 8, count.index)` this creates /24 from your VPC's cider range. Do you want to hard-code your own ranges as a variable?

Comment: yes i want to take the data from user so in case same setup can be used multiple times without depending on cidr

Comment: i want to create only 2 subnets, rather depends on length of availability zone.

Comment: @AliabbasKothawala Please make question specific to your issue.